# Flipping / Sliding Effect with Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, slide

I am trying to make an Flipping / Sliding Effect with Winforms.

To be exact: a effect where the first Form slides/ is pushed out of the screen and the second one slides in.

After a lot of research I came to the conclusion that a Flipping effect is not working in Winforms.

I tried the following things for the sliding effect:

1. Embedding winforms in Wpf Application - using Windowsformshost
   --> Windowsformshost doesn't support animation.
2. Change Location of the Forms
   a. with an Timer 
   b. with loop
   c. separate threads

   -->the form is flickering & does not look professional
3. Screen capture - i.e. screenshots of the forms

   --> same Problem: flickering
4. AnimateWindow Function (API)

   --> the API doesn't support threading 
   --> sliding in AND out of both forms at the same time is not possible.
   --> same Problem: flickering

Additional Infos:

I use C# ,Visual Studio 2010 (Dot net Framework 4.0)
3rd party Controls - Telerik
On my Form are Custom Controls (extended Telerik controls)
I have set Doubblebuffered to True for the controls.

It would be really helpful if somebody could help/suggest to overcome this issue (winforms Flipping/Sliding Effect).

Regards, WickedSquall

Comment: Thank you for the replies.
 
the Requirements have changes a little:
 
The sliding has to be in the Form.
 
This is relative easy, by changing the Control.left value.
 
Alternative to that I try to insert a Custom WPF Control in the Winform witch moves 2 Screenshots with an Animation.
 
I'll update you

Answer (score 4):

The best option would be

**5.** Switch to WPF. It runs on DirectX and you need that.

But I guess that's not an option. The most workable seems your option **3** , moving bitmaps. The flickering should be solvable with double-buffering etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here our final solution:

We decided to bring this issue to a third party who has more experience with graphics.

The best solution with our knowledge moving Pictureboxs with Screenshots and an Timer.

Regards